# Selecting particular CSS file to enable differetn themes for different visitors as per their prior selection

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, themes

I have created a website and have multiple css file that act as different themes. Now I want to enable a person to login and being able to associate a theme of his liking to his account. How to go about it? I also want any unregistered user to be able to change his theme too (I think using cookie I can do it. Any better ideas?). Also, I want to load only that particular CSS file to the visitor's browser rather than loading all CSS files. Names of my CSS files are like main-blue, main-red,main-green etc.

I am new to web development so I would need bit detailed instructions. Please help

Comment: What login script are you currently using? The best way would be to have a cell within your database named `theme` and save their choice to this cell. Within the page loads it will look for their choice within the DB and then load it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use cookies, the use something like this:

```
$css = 'default'; //Fallback theme
if($_COOKIE['theme']) $css = $_COOKIE['theme']; //If the cookie is set, change the theme

echo '<link rel="stylesheet" src="css/' . $css . '.css" />'; //Aply the theme
```

Then just use `setcookie('theme', 'filename', <expiration>)` to set the theme. `<expiration>` is optional (default is session).

If you're using something else than cookies (SESSION, SQL or whatever) just change `$_COOKIE['theme']` to whatever variable you're using.